# What does the return statement in the rxjs pipe actually do or mean?

Tags: rxjs

Trying to learn RxJs, and I found what looks like a nice tutorial on that topic at https://www.learnrxjs.io.

I'm going through their primer section, and I am not clear on what the *return* statement in the pipe() function actually does or what it means. These are a couple of screen shots from their tutorial:

[image: Error and Transform explanation]

In traditional programming, I've always understood a return statement to be an exit - if function A calls function B, and function B has the line `return 1`, then control goes back to function A.

Is that what happens here? If so, in either of these two examples, where am I returning to???

Or what if I don't want to return anywhere but act on the data immediately? For example, in the error handling example, instead of `return makeRequest...`,  I want to do something like `const result = makeRequest...`. Can I do that?

In general I'm having some conceptual difficulties around all the *returns* I've seen used with observables, and any help in explaining what they do/are would be appreciated. So would any other tutorial sites on RxJs.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are all very similar constructs in javascript

```ts
function adder0(a,b){
  return a + b
}
const adder1 = (a,b) => {
  return a + b
}
const adder2 = (a,b) => a + b

console.log(adder0(3,7)) // 10
console.log(adder1(3,7)) // 10
console.log(adder2(3,7)) // 10
```

lets re-write the code from that example but with explicit function definitions (instead of arrow syntax).

```ts
function maker(value){
  return makeRequest(value).pipe(
    catchError(handleError)
  );
}

function actioner(value){
  // take action
}

source.pipe(
  mergeMap(maker)
).subscribe(actioner)
```

The thing to notice is that you never actually call these functions. RxJS does that for you. You give them a function and they'll call it when they're good and ready based on the spec for a given operator.